# RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin - I'm getting this error if I run .exe file but able to run with .py in pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, runtime-error

I'm learning Python newly. I have python script that takes input from user. If I run this script in `pycharm`, I'm getting the required output, but getting `"RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin" this error in .exe file which I converter with pyinstaller.`

Please guide me as how to run my .exe file with user inputs. Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import sys

downloaded_file = input("Enter Downloaded file name: ")
customer_file = input("Enter Customer file name: ")


df_portal = pd.read_excel(f"{downloaded_file}.xls")

df_customer_zyme = pd.read_excel(f"{customer_file}.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need to build your pyinstaller with "console" option:

https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-c